# Redirect url having query string to 404 page using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect  "http://www.example.com/?ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=1" this url to `404` page through `.htaccess`. Please provide solution.
Thanks

Comment: share more info like any specific url or data in url?

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to do your job for you. Have a go first, then come back and ask for help. Stop being so f*cking lazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your document root's htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=1$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: It works but i tried similar for another url i.e "www.chemionix.com/?ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=2‎" but it will redirect to http://www.chemionix.com/?ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=2%E2%80%8E not on the error page. here is my code  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=1$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ac=2&slt=8&slr=1&lpt=2$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [L,R=404]

Answer (score 0):

Detail document for modrewrite and htaccess :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

You can generate custom htaccess file with:

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/